# Multicast on same host with multiple clients

Tags: c, linux, broadcast, multicast

i'm working on a linux host where several applications (currently 3) are communicating with multicast on address 224.0.0.1. I set SO_REUSEADDR and IP_MULTICAST_LOOP. Sometimes it works as expected: 1 application sends data and the 2 other clients receive a frame with the same data. But often 1 client reads the same frame 2 times and the other client then receives nothing.

How can i ensure, that 1 client doesn't read the same frame several times, so that other clients also receive the frame?

Since such network topics are new to me, i'm open for better ways if i'm going the wrong way here.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I have a vague suspicion this doesn't work - it's handled in commercial products like TibcoRV by having a local daemon that reflects messages back to processes on the same machine, and only the daemon interacts with the multicast interface.

Comment: Do you know a better way to do this? Bandwith, traffic etc is not important, since it's just for evaluation purpose. I only chose multicast, because i thought it is the best for this.

Comment: Hmm, why not use something like a RabbitMQ fanout exchange, that will ensure that all the processes get the messages in full.